# When exactly are elements added to change sets?

Tags: change-set

When exactly are design elements added to change sets? Are they added when I add the element to the change set or are they pulled in when the change set is uploaded? I've looked at the online documentation, but what I've read doesn't clarify the timing.

In other words, if I do the following:

1. Add an element to a change set
2. edit the element
3. upload the change set

will the uploaded change set contain the edit from step 2 or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The change set definition is just the list of items to be retrieved when the package is uploaded.

This is similar to the package.xml file which instructs Eclipse/ant which metadata files should be retrieved during an operation.

> will the uploaded change set contain the edit from step 2 or not?

Yes, it will.